# Postgresql update - Using ArrayList

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I am getting an exception on update of postgres:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type...

Here is the code where in I build the sql statement dynamically and append the params:

```
public Boolean update(UserData usrData){
    String sqlUpdateUser = "UPDATE \"USER\" ";
    String sqlSetValues = "SET";
    String sqlCondition = "Where \"USER_ID\" = ? ";

    List<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();
    List<Integer> types = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if(usrData.getFirstName() != null){
        sqlSetValues = sqlSetValues.concat(" \"FIRST_NAME\" = ? ").concat(", ");
        params.add(usrData.getFirstName());
        types.add(Types.VARCHAR);

    }

    if(usrData.getMiddleName() != null){
        sqlSetValues = sqlSetValues.concat("\"MIDDLE_NAME\" = ? ");
        params.add(usrData.getMiddleName());
        types.add(Types.VARCHAR);
    }

    params.add(usrData.getUserId());
    types.add(Types.BIGINT);

    Object[] updateParams = new Object[params.size()];
    updateParams = params.toArray(updateParams);

    Integer[] paramTypes = new Integer[types.size()];
    paramTypes = types.toArray(paramTypes);


    sqlUpdateUser = sqlUpdateUser.concat(sqlSetValues).concat(sqlCondition);
    int rowsAffected = this.jdbcTemplate.update(sqlUpdateUser, updateParams, paramTypes);

    if(rowsAffected > 0){
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }else{
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }

}
```

And table schema for the USER table is:

```
"FIRST_NAME" character varying(50),
"MIDDLE_NAME" character varying(50),
```

If I do an update statically without using the collection, but by using Array, I see no issue. 
Code snipped using arrays:

```
Object[] param = { usrData.getFirstName(), usrData.getMiddleName(), usrData.getUserId() };
int[] type = { Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.BIGINT };
int rowsAffected = this.jdbcTemplate.update(sqlUpdateUser, param, type);
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks
K

Answer (score 0):

Move these lines

```
    Object[] updateParams = new Object[params.size()];
    updateParams = params.toArray(updateParams);

    Integer[] paramTypes = new Integer[types.size()];
    paramTypes = types.toArray(paramTypes);
```

beneath

```
    params.add(usrData.getUserId());
    types.add(Types.INTEGER);
```

In your case you are missing to add usrData.getUserId() in updateParams.

Comment: Can you check the exact values of  sqlUpdateUser , updateParams,  paramTyoes being passed in this line - int rowsAffected = this.jdbcTemplate.update(sqlUpdateUser, updateParams, paramTypes);

Comment: I checked these - UpdateParams value: n_update4 |  G_update4 | 66 & Corresponding ParamTypes values 12 | 12 | -5 .. And these values are same when passed as a normal Array and when passed as an array created from an ArrayList..... So with this issues, I am stuck on how do I dynamically construct an Update statement..

Comment: Can you please paste the whole stack trace .. It will show where conversion exception happened